# Grails script cant find field of superclass in a subclass

Tags: java, oop, grails

My Grails app has a number of domain classes, but two of them are ChannelSpecification and AlarmSpecification. Since all alarms are channels but not all channels are alarms I decided to specify them as follows:

```
package channeldatabase

class ChannelSpecification {
    ...
    Integer visibility
    ...
}
```

and

```
package channeldatabase

class AlarmSpecification extends ChannelSpecification {
    ...
}
```

This works just as expected in most places except for Grails scripts where this sort of thing gets me an:

```
| Error Error executing script GenerateTxSpecXml: No such property: visibilty for class: channeldatabase.AlarmSpecification
Possible solutions: visibility (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the error says `No such property: visibilty`  not visibil**i**ty. Typo?

Comment: *facepalm* Yup, sorry. Stared at that for an hour. Thanks!